# Jinja2: format + join the items of a list

Tags: python, jinja2, ansible

`play_hosts` is a list of all machines for a play. I want to take these and use something like `format()` to rewrite them like `rabbitmq@%s` and then join them together with something like `join()`. So:

```
{{ play_hosts|format(???)|join(', ') }}
```

All the examples of format use piping where the input is the format string and not a list. Is there a way to use these (or something else) to accomplish what I want? The output should looks something like:

```
['rabbitmq@server1', 'rabbitmq@server2', rabbitmq@server3', ...]
```

The jinja2 doc describes format like this:

```
format(value, *args, **kwargs)
```

Apply python string formatting on an object:

```
{{ "%s - %s"|format("Hello?", "Foo!") }}
-> Hello? - Foo!
```

So it gives three kinds of input but doesn't describe those inputs in the example, which shows one in the pipe and the other two passed in via args.  Is there a keyword arg to specify the string that's piped?  Please help, python monks!

Comment: would this work? (I've never used jinja) `{% for host in play_hosts %}` `{{ "rabbitmq@%s"|format(host) }}` `{% endfor %}`

Comment: Seems like a list comprehension is all you need.

Comment: @Barmar list comps are not supported by jinja2

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In ansible you can use regex_replace filter:

```
{{ play_hosts | map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', 'rabbitmq@\\1') | list }}
```

Comment: Simplification: `{{ play_hosts | map('regex_replace', '^', 'rabbitmq@') | list }}`

Answer (score 14):

I believe another way would be using the `joiner` global function, as you can read in http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#list-of-global-functions:

> A joiner is passed a string and will return that string every time it’s called, except the first time (in which case it returns an empty string). You can use this to join things

So your code would be something like:

```
[
{% set comma = joiner(",") %}    
{% for host in play_hosts %}
    {{ comma() }}
    {{ "rabbitmq@%s"|format(host) }}
{% endfor %}
]
```

Answer (score 13):

You can create custom filter

```
# /usr/share/ansible/plugins/filter/format_list.py (check filter_plugins path in ansible.cfg)

def format_list(list_, pattern):
    return [pattern % s for s in list_]


class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'format_list': format_list,
        }
```

and use it

```
{{ play_hosts | format_list('rabbitmq@%s') }}
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution. Your Jinja2 code will quickly get unwieldy if you try to do it all within your playbook.

Comment: Such `format_list` should be really part of Jinja2!

Answer (score 11):

You could simply `join` not only by `,` but also add the prefix together with it. Now that's not very pythonic or sophisticated but a very simple working solution:

```
[rabbitmq@{{ play_hosts | join(', rabbitmq@') }}]
```

Comment: Repetition is not nice, but looks cleaner than `regex_replace`. Really missing a clean filter in jinja2. +1 for the workaround

Comment: This however will leave a dangling `rabbitmq@` in case of an empty list.