# How to append to a list where the string you're appending is being constucted dynamically in the play

Tags: ansible

Pulling my hair out. I know I've done this eons ago with much older versions of ansible. I haven't touched ansible much so don't recall how I did this. This seems so ridiculously easy at first glance so obviously something stupid i'm overlooking.

Given sample inventory, nothing fancy:

Note: removing FQDN's for brevity.
Note: this automation is working with a large number of hosts and many many more variables than I'm representing here. This is a majorly dumbed down example.

```
[nodes]
foo1
foo2
foo3

[all:vars]
minio_proto=http
disks_per_node=64
```

Ultimately I need to build a string that wraps text around the hostnames. This is for minio if you are familiar with it.

You start a server by speficying all the nodes and the disk paths:

```
minio server http://foo1/data/disk{0...79} http://foo2/data/disk{0...63} http://foo3/data/disk{0...63}
```

So inside my play I need to construct this string that eventually gets passed to a shell command to start the server on each node.

So I have a playbook (eventually this will be a role) that will be run once, not for every host, just to construct this server parameter.

I've tried so many permutations of stuff I can't possibly list them all but here's just one of my latest stabs:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  become: true
  ignore_errors: false
  vars:
    minio_startup1: []
    minio_startup2: []
  tasks:
  - name: Verifying hosts are up and we can become root
    become: true
    ping:
 # THIS WORKS FINE, APPENDING A SIMPLE VARIABLE WORKS
  - name: Building minio startup parameter
    set_fact:
      minio_startup1: "{{ minio_startup1 + [item] }}"
    with_items:
      - "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
  - debug: var=minio_startup1
 # DOING STUFF LIKE THIS DOES NOT WORK
  - name: Building minio startup parameter
    set_fact:
      minio_startup2: "{{ minio_startup2 }} + [{{ minio_proto }}//{{ item }}/data{0...{{ disks_per_node|int - 1 }}}] }}"
    with_items:
      - "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
  - debug: var=minio_startup2
```

Basically at this point in the playbook I want a list that looks like this:

```
[ 'http://foo1/data{0...63}', 'http://foo2/data{0...63}', 'http://foo2/data{0...63}']
```

Then later in the playbook, I can concatenate this into a single string I can feed my minio container thru a shell command:

```
{{ minio_startup|join(' ') }}
```

I know I did this years ago but after 3 hrs of hair pulling it eludes me.

*** UPDATE ***

Well I figured out a way, not sure if this is the best. If interested, this is what I did. It looks like you can use '~' to concatenate items inside the []'s. I still had to do the math of determinig the ending disk index number in a separate variable. (disk_ending_index)

```
      minio_startup2: "{{ minio_startup2  + [ minio_proto ~ '//' ~ item ~ '/data{0...' ~ disk_ending_index ~ '}' ] }}"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jinja2: format + join the items of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35183744/jinja2-format-join-the-items-of-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Single-Quoted Style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2788097). The playbook below

```
- hosts: foo1:foo2:foo3
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    minio_proto: http
    disks_per_node: 64
    minio_startup: []
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        minio_startup: '{{ minio_startup +
                           [minio_proto ~ "://" ~  item ~
                           "/data{0.." ~ disks_per_node ~ "}"] }}'
      loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
      run_once: true
    - debug:
        var: minio_startup
      run_once: true
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ minio_startup|join(' ') }}"
      run_once: true
```

gives (abridged)

```
ok: [foo1] => {
    "minio_startup": [
        "http://foo1/data{0..63}",
        "http://foo2/data{0..63}",
        "http://foo3/data{0..63}"
    ]
}

ok: [foo1] => {
    "msg": "http://foo1/data{0..63} http://foo2/data{0..63} http://foo3/data{0..63}"
}
```

Quoting from [Single-Quoted Style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2788097):

> *... the “\” and “"” characters may be freely used. This restricts single-quoted scalars to printable characters ...*